# Get FACEBOOK posts from other users who publish their posts

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to receive users of a particular user on Facebook. I am creating a Discord BOT and want to share the retrieved posts on the Discord channel as soon as possible. I'm familiar with DiscordBOT, but I'm having trouble getting Facebook posts.

- I first attempted to use Facebook Webhook to get post notifications immediately, but this seems to get only my posts.
- Then I tried to use the API to get posts from a specific user. But this always shows a permission error and doesn't let me get it.

  ```
  Getting “(#100) Pages Public Content Access requires either app secret proof or an app token
  ```
- I have considered using an external service like IFTTT. However, this is unusable for me due to the terrible delay.

Is there any solution?

Comment: Are you talking about users, or pages? The error message seems to be referring to the latter. If you want to get public content from other pages, then you need to submit your app for usage of that feature. If we are talking user posts, on their own timelines - you need the user’s explicit permission for that.